# How to grab a random element from an array without grabbing the same element more than once?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift, random, arc4random

When I grab an element from an array using the `arc4random_uniform()` method, the same element the array is often grabbed more than once. I am trying to make it so each element in the array is grabbed only once. The reason I'm trying to do this is so more than one cells in a `UITableView` don't have the same text. Here's the array for the text of the cells in the `UITableView`:

```
var definitions = ["Used to carry the pharoah","Used to carry bodies as a ceremony","Had a flat deck to carry a farmer's treasure","Daily, it made a trip around the world to carry Ra","Towed by smaller boats, carrying heavy objects","Used for business and pleasure by officials/nobles","Carried most Egyptians and some goods"]
```

In my `viewDidLoad()` method, I have done this to call random elements of `definitions`:

```
self.boats = [Boats(name: definitions[Int(arc4random_uniform(7))]),Boats(name: definitions[Int(arc4random_uniform(7))]),Boats(name: definitions[Int(arc4random_uniform(7))]),Boats(name: definitions[Int(arc4random_uniform(7))]),Boats(name: definitions[Int(arc4random_uniform(7))]),Boats(name: definitions[Int(arc4random_uniform(7))]),Boats(name: definitions[Int(arc4random_uniform(7))])]
```

How can I alter my code so two elements aren't displayed twice in my `UITableView`? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to randomly sort the array?

Comment: What you are looking for is called "random shuffle" or "random permutation". The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) is one possible implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a list of the random index values and if a subsequent random index is in that list, then skip it and generate another random index.

Comment: This is not the best way to do this, if you want to get all of the elements it gets very inefficient towards the end.

Comment: Agreed.  An alternative would be to use a linked list with n elements.  Generate a random index i, 1 <= i <= n (assuming a 1 offset), grab the value, remove the item from the list (so the list is now n-1 elements) and do it again, this time generating a random index i between 1 and n-1.  Or some variation on that theme.

Comment: Better alternatives would be to shuffle the set of values and iterate through the shuffled set (to get the entire set), or to use [Floyd's unique subset algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157311/randomly-skip-x-percentage-of-words-from-java-iterator/27160949#27160949) if you want a subset.